# Getting syxtax error using JSONP call back - angularJs

Tags: angularjs, json, jsonp

Service

```
some.factory('homeService', ['$http', function($http){

        return {

            getEvents : function(url) {

                return $http.jsonp(url);
            }
        }

    }]);
```

Controller

```
homeService.getEvents("http://server.some.io/s/first?callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
    .then(
        function(response){
            $scope.events = response.data.events;
        });
```

**Error**: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token **:**

Which is: json object: `{"meta": {"has_next": false, "status": 200, "place":.....`

Error is pointing right after the "meta"

Any clue of what is going on?

Comment: Of course. your "JSON" response isn't a "JSONP" response. you can't fix this problem with javascript. It appears as though `server.some.io` doesn't support JSONP.

Comment: True. It's returning regular json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server was not returning JSONP format. Fixed on the server.